# Indexing Icons in multiple Custom HTML5 Video Controls

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple HTML5 videos being controlled and I need to alter the Play and Pause Icons on the player that the user has clicked on.

Now the method to do this for a single player is just

```
$('.glyphicon-pause').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-play');
```

but when part of multiple players (as per the indexed list below) all players are affected if this simple approach is used, for example

```
        function onplayCallback(index) {
        // Event listener for the play/pause button
        playButton[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (popUpPlayer[index].paused == true) {
                popUpPlayer[index].play();
                 $('.glyphicon-play').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-pause'); <-----here
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                popUpPlayer[index].pause();
                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                 $('.glyphicon-pause').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-play');
            }
        });
```

I have tried replacing the line above with

```
 $(this).attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-pause');
```

but the problem is is this just adds another pause icon.

Is there a way around this?  I have tried `$(this).removeClass()` etc but none of those methods work.

For completeness, here is the html

```
<div id="video-controls">
            <a href="#" id="play-pause_<?php echo $i+1;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a> 
            <input type="range" id="seek-bar_1" value="0"> 
            <a href="#" id="btnMute_<?php echo $i+1;?>"><span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></a> 
            <input type="range" id="volume-bar_<?php echo $i+1;?>" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1"> 
            <a href="#" id="btnFullscreen_<?php echo $i+1;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span></a>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that `$(this)` didn't work because it's pointing to the `<a>` (currentTarget), but you want the inner `<span>`? Did you log the values of `this`?

It depends on your layout but if the span is your whole button then `e.target` should point to it.

```
playButton[index].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   console.log(e.target); // check this is what you want
   var $span = $(e.target);

   if (popUpPlayer[index].paused == true) {
     $span.removeClass('glyphicon-pause').addClass('glyphicon-play');
   } else {
     $span.removeClass('glyphicon-play').addClass('glyphicon-pause');
   }
});
```

Comment: I thought I had logged it but obviously not otherwise I might have spotted this - sometimes we get too embedded in the problem and miss the obvious - but thankyou this has fixed it.